# creation of realm file in App-Group Folder does not work under WatchOS (WatchKit Extension)

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, realm

The following code works under iOS-8.x / Swift-1.2 / WatchKit-1.0

```
    // create Realm_DB-File in shared App-Groups Folder
    let directory: NSURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier(AppConstants.APP_GROUP_IDENTIFIER_KEY)!
    let realmPath = directory.path!.stringByAppendingPathComponent(AppConstants.REALM_FILENAME_KEY)
    playerRealm = Realm.init(path: realmPath)
```

But it doesn't work under iOS-9.0.1 / Swift-2.0 / WatchOS-2.0

The two error messages are:

1.) 'stringByAppendingPatchComponent' is unavailable: Use URLByAppendingPathComponent on NSURL instead

2.) Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

[image]

Any help appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your first issue, you need to cast:

`directory.path as NSString`

since the path is returning as a `String`, which in Swift doesn't offer the `stringByAppendingPathComponent` method.

Second, Swift 2.0 has new error handling, so methods that can throw an error are labeled `throws`. These methods then require you to add `try` before the call. See Apple's docs on this: [Swift Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html)

To disable the error handling if you know that the path is guaranteed to work you can simple write:

```
playerRealm = try! Realm(path: realmPath)
```